# Decode a A/V stream in c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, avcodec

I'm working on a C# program, which can read an Audio/Video stream  and should separate it to a Video file and Audio file.
Input stream is a Byte-Raw array
My question is How I can separate Video frame and Audio frame from a Byte Array?
(suppose that i know video and audio details about that streaming)

P.S: Sorry for my bad EN :'(

Comment: you... just use the"video and audio details about that streaming" that you apparently know, and ... do it? personally I'd start by looking for a pre-existing A/B lib...

Comment: me?! :D ... i know details but how get my frames from that byte array?

Comment: by applying the AV encoding format rules... and note that it really won't be trivial - you need to work forwards from the last key frame, etc